# plantUML in latex?

Tags: latex, plantuml

Is it possible to use plantUML inside a latex document?

One workaround would be to convert plantUML into tikzpicture and integrate it in the latex document. That seems a bit too much effort to me, especially with updates.

I am using overleaf and TeXiFy, the document generation should work on both latex editors.

If a direct integration is possible, I would like to see an example.

thanks

Comment: Did you look at https://plantuml.com/latex?

Comment: This would be the external tikz picture generation, there is no way to generate it directly in latex. If there is a similarly simple alternative to generate diagrams in latex, I would be interested.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/koppor/plantuml

Comment: Because it might be useful to someone: using an [uml package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-umlcd?lang=en) that's based on TikZ, you can use TeXiFy's [TikZ preview](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Preview#TikZ-preview).

Comment: If you want to abstract to Markdown with Pandoc (LaTeX runs under the hood to generate PDF files), it's very clean. There's a filter https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/diagram-generator that works very well to embed PlantUML in markdown as a code fence. If you need control of LaTeX you can put the instructions in the markdown.

Answer (score 0):

I will begin by answering your first question:
**Yes** you can use PlantUML diagrams directly defined inline in your tex file, if you use the plantuml package.

consider following example `test.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plantuml}
\begin{document}
\section{PlantUML}

Let's insert a UML diagram:\\

\begin{plantuml}
  @startuml
  Alice -> Bob: TEST1
  @enduml
\end{plantuml}

And another one:\\

\begin{plantuml}
  @startuml
  Alice -> Bob: TEST2
  @enduml
\end{plantuml}
\end{document}
```

use lualatex with the -shell-escape option to generate `test.pdf` which will look like this:

[image: test.pdf]

now you mentioned you use texify and overleaf:

for texify you would need to edit your command like so:

```
texify --pdf --engine=lualatex --tex-option="-shell-escape" test.tex
```

overleaf apparently supports plantuml by running a plantuml server for diagram generation, meaning you only need to set it to use the lualatex engine in the project settings.

The -shell-escape option gives latex permission to call foreign programs, in our case java is called to execute plantuml to produce the plantuml diagrams we want.

Be mindful to only use -shell-escape with trutworthy latex files to avoid harmful consequences.